# Firebase Array using normal array methods?

Tags: arrays, firebase

I was trying to get the length of a firebase array:

```
    var collectionObj = $firebaseArray(new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/publicData/Collections'));
    $scope.collections = collectionObj;
    console.log($scope.collections.length);
```

In the console this returns 0. However in the HTML view {{collections.length}} returns the number that I expect. Is there a way to access this number like I tried to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to print the length before the array is even loaded. Html gets updated after the array is loaded. Try this -

```
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/publicData/Collections');
var collections = $firebaseArray(ref);

collections.$loaded().then(function(){
console.log(collections.length);
});
```

Refer [this](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-loaded) for more information.

Comment: That will work indeed Just keep in mind that the `collections` may be updated after the initial load and `$loaded()` will not fire for those updates.